# При обращении к API, все зависает | C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Выполняю обычный GET запрос на C# пытаясь дозвониться до своего API. С любой звонилки легко дозваниваюсь и получаю данные, но в своем WPF приложении по нажатии кнопки, которая тригерит этот код, все виснет.

```
        public static dynamic GetUsers()
    {
        var url = "https://admin.mineboxes.ru/api/v1/mineboxes/players/view";

        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        
        httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Token c4598fae95e90fd0507ebdfe0fba";


        var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
        }
        
    }
```

Даже на дебаге зависает и никаких исключений, именно вот на этом куске:

```
var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Я подозреваю, что либо я не так составил запрос, хотя он временами работает! Либо надо его делать как-то асинхронно и я никак не могу найти как и в каком месте await повесить. (Токен невалидный в примере, но должно хотябы присылать что-то вроде "не тот токен".

Comment: Почитайте документацию про `WebRequest`, увидите там "не стоит использовать в новых проектах!", другими словами: `WebRequest` устарел! Также, `dynamic` - зло, если вы его используете, то значит вы делаете явно очень серьезный костыль. Ну а по поводу вопроса: пора вам узнать, что такое "асинхронное программирование" (`async/await`).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это даже больше чем я ожидал от ответа!

Comment: Спасибо, что вправили мозг, понял как сделать асинхронно для этого нужно прочитать в соответствующем разделе на Metanit про C#, вебреквест в топку, для запроса теперь использую RESTSHARP. Документация очень хорошая у него. Dynamic тоже в топку, научился по человечески сериализовать JSON.

Comment: `RESTSHARP` - не советую для начала изучения, научитесь работать с чистым C#, а уж затем облегчайте себе жизнь при помощи разных библиотек. HttpClient очень простой, поймете все его тонкости, поймете как лучше работать с тем же RestSharp.